# Url format with :

Tags: api, express

Try to build an API using express and was told look into URLs with the form /path/:id/extension.

The path and extension are made up, but what i was sent follows that format. I have never seen anything with the : in the route.

Can anybody interpret this and tell me what it means? Is this standard practice?

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Route parameters https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: >> https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:id` refers to `req.params()` object. Effectively it is how you pass variable data, eg. you would replace `:id` with the specific id you are referring to in the URL path, and build your id-specific logic around it, referring to the value as `req.params.id`.

See the [Express Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard syntax does Express, the colon prefix denotes a parameter variable.

In the route handler, the URL pattern you describe would match /path/5/extension, where 5 is now accessible through req.params.id.  You can read more in the ExpressJS docs under Routing.